# What is the logic of parsing datetime with years and months?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

I am not sure why '200011' parses to 2000-11-01 with '%Y%m' as the format when '200013' with '%Y%m' fails and '200011' with '%Y%m%d' succeeds. See code:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('200013', '%Y%m')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File ".../lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 346, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 3
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('200011', '%Y%m')
datetime.datetime(2000, 11, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('200011', '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Because `%Y%m` is going to parse as `YYYYMM` so `MM` will be `13` in your example but there is no 13th month.

Comment: "*I am not sure why '200011' parses to 2000-01-01 with '%Y%m' as the format*" -- it doesn't. As your code demonstrates, it parses to 2000-11-1.

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: @EliSadoff That makes sense, what doesnt make sense is why %m and %d seem to be matching single digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: The Python documentation neglects to mention that the **zero-padding month is optional**.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> pattern = '%Y%m'
>>> datetime.strptime('20161', pattern).strftime(pattern)
'201601'  # Note an extra "0" has appeared
```

The time formats for `strptime` and `strftime` come from the C standard libraries.  The Python documentation is somewhat lacking on a few important details here, the [relevant section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) in Python documentation just says:

> %m    Month as a zero-padded decimal number.

However it is also mentioned

> The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common.

The behaviour which is causing surprising results here, i.e. the handling of leading zeros, is better documented for C:

> %Y
>   The full year {4}; leading zeros shall be permitted but shall not be required. A leading '+' or '-' character shall be permitted before any leading zeros but shall not be required.
>
> %m
>   The month number [01,12]; **leading zeros shall be permitted but shall not be required.**
>
> %d
>   The day of the month [01,31]; leading zeros shall be permitted but shall not be required.

Emphasis mine.  Source [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html).

---

So with the knowledge that leading zeros may or may not be present, all the cases mentioned are correctly accounted for:

```
datetime.strptime('200013', '%Y%m')  # Can not parse
```

Since 13 is not a valid month, parsing is forced to take 1 is the month with leading zeros omitted.  Then you get `ValueError` because the parser did not know what to do with the extra data "3".

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('200011', '%Y%m')  # Parses to 1st Nov
```

The parser takes November (11) as the month.  Day just defaults to 1.  It is not possible to take January as the month here, because that would leave extra data unaccounted for with this pattern - there would be an extra trailing '1' leftover.  Therefore, the parser must be greedy and consume '11' for the month.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('200011', '%Y%m%d')  # Parses to 1st Jan
```

Here we see that '200011' can be successfully parsed by *either* pattern `%Y%m` and `%Y%m%d`.  If you parse with `%Y%m%d` pattern, then you are forced to take month as January (1) otherwise there is no remaining data to fill `%d`.  Note that leading zeros are also optional for `%d`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no corresponding month for the integer 13, so you'll have to add a specifier to parse the `3` after `1` has been parsed as the month:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('200013', '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 3, 0, 0)
```

`'200011'` works because `11` corresponds to November and can be safely parsed as a month, while the day defaults to 1 when not specified.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I don't really know why someone downvoted it.

Comment: But %m and %d are supposed to be 2 digits? So why do they match single digits?

Answer (score 0):

Example:
Month, date, hour and min missing, so these are set to defaults:

> > > datetime.datetime.strptime('2000', '%Y')
> > >       datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)

Month, hour and min set to defaults:

> > > datetime.datetime.strptime('200012', '%Y%d')
> > >       datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 12, 0, 0)

In your example, its looking for a month as second param but there is no '13' month - datetime.datetime.strptime('200013', '%Y%m')

But when you say, datetime.datetime.strptime('200013', '%Y%m%d'), it looks for year: 2000, month, since 13 isn't valid, it takes 1 as month and 3 as day

Lastly, in this case: datetime.datetime.strptime('200011', '%Y%m'), it looks for year, 2000 valid year, looks for month, 11 is valid month. Now rest is set to defaults (just like the examples I gave at the very top).

On that note the following command, defaults month and takes 13 as valid date.

> > > datetime.datetime.strptime('200013', '%Y%d')
> > >       datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 13, 0, 0)